# Swift: using object factory results in unrecognised selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, researchkit

Am using [Josh Smith's ObjectFactory](http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/06/05/instantiating-classes-by-name-in-swift/) for instantiating classes by name in Swift. But the below code I tried results in unrecognised selector.

```
if let survey = surveyFactory.createInstance(className: className, initializer: "initWithStyle", argument: textChoiceStyle!.rawValue , argument2:  textChoices!)
```

The class name I passed is **ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat** and the resulting Obj C expression I need to achieve in Swift as below

```
ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat *asd = [[ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat alloc]initWithStyle:<#(ORKChoiceAnswerStyle)#> textChoices:<#(NSArray * __nonnull)#>];
```

But am getting it as unrecognised selector in the object factory method

```
    static id OBJCInitWithArg(id  target,
                          SEL initializer,
                          id  argument, id argument2)
{  IMP imp = [target methodForSelector:initializer];
    id (*initFunc)(id, SEL, id, id) = (void *)imp;
   return initFunc(target, initializer, argument, argument2);
}
```

And am getting this error in the console

```
[ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat initWithStyle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to use `initWithStyle:`.

Comment: I tried still same `-[ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat initWithStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe6c0dcb200`

Comment: Actually, `initWithStyle:` isn't available. What did you expect it to do? See http://researchkit.org/docs/Classes/ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat.html#//api/name/initWithStyle:textChoices:

Comment: to myself - "Where am I going wrong?"  me - I am completely wrong *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *selector* for your *initializer* is [`initWithStyle:textChoices:`](http://researchkit.org/docs/Classes/ORKTextChoiceAnswerFormat.html#//api/name/initWithStyle:textChoices:).